SAP HANA: Connection to database server lost; check server and network status [System error: null]
We are using SAP HANA to perform some high volume transaction via our Java application using ngdbc driver. We are seeing some intermittent connection failure issues with the below JDBC exception.
Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLNonTransientConnectionExceptionSapDB: Connection to database server lost; check server and network status [System error: null] 
ngdbc driver version used:  2.12.9
Number of parallel connections: 100 (as there are 100 separate threads each using a different connection)
Generally what we have seen is, ngdbc always appends the reason for this class of exception. For e.g.
Connection to database server lost; check server and network status. java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
But in our case, there is no sub reason attached for the Connection to database server lost.
Could anyone provide a reason/possible scenarios this exception can occur, specially [System error: null]?
The intent is to reproduce the issue on demand, so that we can isolate and fix it.
I tired to recreate the issue by adjusting the max_external_connections in SAP HANA to 10 and then intentionally trying to opening more connections then configured expecting to reproduce the issue. But unfortunately application keeps running without any exceptions.
